# Basic Authentication not working for creating new post using WP REST API 2.0

Tags: json, wordpress, .htaccess, curl, wp-api

I'm trying to create a new post using cUrl on my Wordpress 4.3.1 site with below plugins:

- [WP BASIC Auth 1.1.3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-basic-auth/)
- [WP REST API 2.0-beta4](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API)

I've added below code to my htaccess.conf file, because [this thread told me so](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1335):

`<IfModule !php5_module>
    Define USE_PHP_FPM
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>`

Type in command line:

`curl --data-binary "@updated-post.json" -H "Content-Type: application/javascript" --user "my_admin_user_name":"my_admin_password" http://www.mysite.nu/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Contents of **updated-post.json**:

`{
    "title": "Hello Updated World!",
    "content_raw": "<p>Howdy updated content.<\/p>",
    "date": "2013-04-01T14:00:00+10:00"
}`

Error code:

`[{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"You don't have permission to do this.","data":{"status":403}}]`

The GET request does work. Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have this same issue.

Comment: Solved it by using a non bitnami instance

Comment: Not familiar with Bitnami but after looking it, looks like a Cloud hosting platform.  So was the issue with the hosting provider?

Comment: Yes. After switching to a different host (non-aws) with softaculous as "wordpress install" everything worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem is in the Basic Auth plugin. WP-API guys [recommend](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1572) using their own plugin and this solution works for me.

1. Deactivate all activated basic auth plugins in your WordPress dashboard
2. On the machine your WordPress is running go to the plugin folder
3. Run

   git clone https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth.git
4. Go to your WordPress admin dashboard, plugins page. *JSON Basic Authentication* should be in the list. Activate it.

Now creating a record via POST request should work.